# For loop to check if three array's indexes match, if so create different objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to check three different arrays to see if their indexes match up. If they match an object is created. The third array may have less items in the array. If the third array has less items, then the previous two arrays should continue checking their indexes for a match and create a different object. The array indexes that match the ones in the "seqIds" array should add "seqId" as a property, the indexes in the other two arrays that don't match with a "seqId" index don't get the "seqId" property.

> Edit: The invIds and invTypes arrays will always be the same length.

Example arrays:

```
invIds:   [1, 2, 3, 4];
invTypes: ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
seqIds:   [10, 11];
```

The invs array should consist of these objects:

```
invs: [
       {
         "invId": 1,
         "invType": "A",
         "seqId": 10
        },
        {
          "invId": 2,
          "invType": "B",
          "seqId": 11
        },
        {
         "invId": 3,
         "invType": "C"
        },
        {
         "invId": 4,
         "invType": "D"
        }
      ];
```

The for loop I wrote:

```
var invs = [];

for (var invI = 0; invI < this.state.invIds.length; invI++) {
  for (var invT = 0; invT < this.state.invTypes.length; invT++) {
    for (var invS = 0; invS < this.state.invSeqIds.length; invS++) {
      if (invI === invT && invT === invS) {
        invs.push({
          seqId: this.state.invSeqIds[invS],
          userId: this.state.invIds[invI],
          invTypeCd: this.state.invTypes[invT],
          importId: randInt
        });
      }
    }
    if (invI === invT) {
      invs.push({
        userId: this.state.invIds[invI],
        invTypeCd: this.state.invTypes[invT],
        importId: randInt
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The for loop I wrote is not adding into the array properly, it does this:

```
{"invId": 1, "invType": "A", "seqId": 10}
{"invId": 1, "invType": "A"}
{"invId": 2, "invType": "B", "seqId": 11}
{"invId": 2, "invType": "B"}
{"invId": 3, "invType": "C"}
{"invId": 4, "invType": "D"}
```

Comment: it's consisting of a few small and simple problems, trying to solve them together is the problem

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: `invIds` and `invTypes` will always have same length? Also, your desired output is the  example you post as `invs: [...` ?

Comment: it is very simple. I've posted the answer check it out, see if it right!

Comment: Yes, invIds and invTypes will always have same length, but not seqIds. Also, yes, that array of objects is my desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to solve this is by using a [`while-statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) along with the operator [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to check for the index of the source array.

```js
let invIds = [1, 2, 3, 4],
  invTypes = ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  seqIds = [10, 11],
  result = [],
  i = 0;

while (i in invIds && i in invTypes) {
  result[i] = Object.create(null);
  result[i].invId = invIds[i];
  result[i].invType = invTypes[i];
  if (i in seqIds) result[i].seqId = seqIds[i];
  i++;
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, since, this doesn't solve the described problem.Elements of first two arrays should be joined only if the indexes match. I.e invIds = [1, 2, 3], invTypes = ["A", "B", "C", "D"] will populate element {invType: "D"} without invId.

Comment: yeah, that helped. but, I think to shorten the code, I would just make a while (not do..while) loop with the statement from your if clause.

Comment: @SimDim yes, I realized that a minute ago.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant :thumbsup: :muscle:

Comment: @SimDim I made an update to my post, the first two arrays, invIds and invTypes will always be the same length.

Answer (score 1):

this is want you want right? Just use a temporary variable to store the object property and push to the invs.

if `seqIds` has less number of elements check before assigning `tmp` a property of  `seqIds` that it exists or not.

```js
let invIds =  [1, 2, 3, 4], invTypes = ["A", "B", "C", "D"], seqIds = [10, 11];

var invs = [];

for (let i = 0; i< invIds.length; ++i) {
  let tmp = {};
  tmp.invIds = invIds[i];
  tmp.invTypes = invTypes[i];
  if(seqIds[i]) tmp.seqIds = seqIds[i];
  
  invs.push(tmp);
}

console.log(invs);
```

Comment: well he updated the question. `invIds` and `invTypes` will be of same length. So there is no problem with my code.

Comment: @ajitkumar I actually didn't clarify, so I updated my post, the first two arrays invIds and invTypes are always the same length.

Comment: if you make an edit to your post, I will be able to remove the downvote (stackoverflow limitation)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var invIds = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var invTypes = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
var seqIds = [10, 11];
var invs = [];

for (var i = 0, length = invIds.length; i < length; i++) {
  var inv = {
    invId: invIds[i],
    invType: invTypes[i]
  };
  if (i < seqIds.length) {
    inv.seqId = seqIds[i];
  }
  invs.push(inv)
}

console.log(invs);
```

Or js ES6 way

```js
const invIds = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const invTypes = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
const seqIds = [10, 11];

const invs = Array(invIds.length)
.fill(undefined).map((_, i) => {
  const result = {
    invId: invIds[i],
    invType: invTypes[i]
  };
  if (seqIds.length > i) result.seqId = seqIds[i];
  return result;
});

console.log(invs)
```

Comment: This works, although the invIds and invTypes array will always be the same length, so the Math.min() is not needed in my case.

Comment: @hypnagogia, I removed Math.min, the code almost the same though. If you do not care about "seqId: undefined" in the resulting object, there could be even less lines of code in any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var invs = this.state.invIds.map(function(item, index){
    var objReturned ={}
    objReturned.invId = item;
    if(this.state.invTypes[index]) objReturned.invType = this.state.invTypes[index]
    if(this.state.invSeqIds[index]) objReturned.seqId = this.state.invSeqIds[index]
    return objReturned;
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using nested loops as that can get quite messy, and it is very difficult to understand and maintain. I would break it down into the following steps:

1. Define a result array where you will store your results, and find the largest data set

   ```
   let invIds = [1, 2, 3, 4];
   let invTypes = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
   let seqIds = [10, 11];

   let result = [];
   let maxLength = Math.max(invIds.length, invTypes.length, seqIds.length);
   ```
2. Iterate over all the indices starting from 0 to the end of the largest data set, and add a new object to the result array if it meets your conditions

   ```
   for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
       let newItem = {};
       // If the property exists and it meets your conditions
       // Also keep in mind if any id is 0, you will have to add to the
       // condition as 0 is a falsy value
       if (invIds[i] || invIds[i] === 0) {
           newItem.invId = invIds[i];
       }

       if (invTypes[i]) {
           newItem.invType = invTypes[i];
       }

       if (seqIds[i] || seqIds[i] === 0) {
           newItem.seqId = seqIds[i];
       }

       result.push(newItem);
   }
   ```